# Trouble with binary string in javascript above character code 128

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, binary, blob

So I'm trying to create and save a binary file locally in javascript using this library: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

It is a bit tricky because I am using GameMaker studio, and the ways I can interact with the javascript is a bit limited, but here's my setup..
Other than the actual filesaver.js from the github repo, my js code is this:

```
var ildablob = new Array();

toArray = function(argument0, argument1)
{
ildablob[argument0] = String.fromCharCode(argument1);
return 1;
}

save = function(argument0)
{
var blob = new Blob(ildablob, {type: "application/octet-stream"});
saveAs(blob, argument0);
return 1;
}
```

Basically, the idea is that I first fill up an array with individual bytes using character codes to create a binary string, which is then made into a blob and saved. This works for binary values below 128, but not above, probably because of some charset issue.. How can I fix this?

For example, if I try filling up the array incrementing from 0-255, this is the content of the resulting binary file, as you can see after 128 bytes the characters suddenly create two bytes each, not one, and it's all wrong:

00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F C2 80 C2 81 C2 82 C2 83 C2 84 C2 85 C2 86 C2 87 C2 88 C2 89 C2 8A C2 8B C2 8C C2 8D C2 8E C2 8F C2 90 C2 91 C2 92 C2 93 C2 94 C2 95 C2 96 C2 97 C2 98 C2 99 C2 9A C2 9B C2 9C C2 9D C2 9E C2 9F C2 A0 C2 A1 C2 A2 C2 A3 C2 A4 C2 A5 C2 A6 C2 A7 C2 A8 C2 A9 C2 AA C2 AB C2 AC C2 AD C2 AE C2 AF C2 B0 C2 B1 C2 B2 C2 B3 C2 B4 C2 B5 C2 B6 C2 B7 C2 B8 C2 B9 C2 BA C2 BB C2 BC C2 BD C2 BE C2 BF C3 80 C3 81 C3 82 C3 83 C3 84 C3 85 C3 86 C3 87 C3 88 C3 89 C3 8A C3 8B C3 8C C3 8D C3 8E C3 8F C3 90 C3 91 C3 92 C3 93 C3 94 C3 95 C3 96 C3 97 C3 98 C3 99 C3 9A C3 9B C3 9C C3 9D C3 9E C3 9F C3 A0 C3 A1 C3 A2 C3 A3 C3 A4 C3 A5 C3 A6 C3 A7 C3 A8 C3 A9 C3 AA C3 AB C3 AC C3 AD C3 AE C3 AF C3 B0 C3 B1 C3 B2 C3 B3 C3 B4 C3 B5 C3 B6 C3 B7 C3 B8 C3 B9 C3 BA C3 BB C3 BC C3 BD C3 BE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `String`, you'd probably be better off using a `Uint8Array` (meaning an array of unsigned bytes in the range 0–255); see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array. For example:

```
ildablob[argument0] = new Uint8Array(1);
ildablob[argument0][0] = argument1;

...

var blob = new Blob(ildablob, {type: "application/octet-stream"});
```

Also, incidentally — `argument0` and `argument1` are terrible variable-names. You mention that you're constrained by GameMaker; is that the reason for this? It seems like there should be some way to fix that.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! Yes, the argument names are related to Gamemaker, but on second thought I think they don't need to be that so I will change it.